# Compile TypeScript while ignoring type errors, but not syntax errors

Tags: javascript, types, compilation, typescript

The TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) emits valid JS even when it has type errors. I am in a situation where I need to compile a TypeScript project to JS but cannot install the required `.d.ts` files for it to correctly type check.

Is there a way I can get `tsc` to ignore any type errors, but still show other kinds of errors such as syntax errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use babel 7 with `@babel/plugin-transform-typescript` to transpile typescript to JS. When you edit, you get the typescript autocomplete and everything. When you compile, types are just stripped away so any typerrors you might have don't matter.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it sounds like just what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can get tsc to ignore any type errors, but still show other kinds of errors such as syntax errors

No with TypeScript files. You can use the `allowJS` option to compile `js` files through typescript compiler and then it will only complain about syntax errors

Comment: Thanks @basarat. Looks like I'll have to work around my problem another way.

Comment: This answer is outdated.